# Como remover um site do Google?

Tags: google, google-sites

Havia encontrado algumas instruções na internet, para remover um site do google, se referiram à uma versão antiga do webmasters tools, que havia esta funcionalidade, porém não consigo achar esta opção na versão atual.

Gostaria de saber como fazer.

**Obs:** Eu queria tirar um site do Google Sites dos resultados de busca do Google. Ali não tem como alterar o robots.txt

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dependendo da indexação atual, são necessários dois passos para garantir que o site não vai voltar a ser indexado e garantir que o mesmo não vai aparecer nos resultados de pesquisa do Google com erro `404`:

## Desabilitar indexação

Para garantir que o site é permanentemente removido dos resultados de pesquisa do Google, é preciso criar um ficheiro na raiz do domínio com o nome `robots.txt` para bloquear o acesso do `crawler` a esse site:

Conteúdo do `robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Estas directivas vão indicar que nada deve ser indexado quando o `crawler` passa nesse site.

## Remover o site e suas páginas dos resultados de pesquisa

Depois de bloqueado o acesso do `crawler` ao domínio, é necessário seguir os seguintes passos para remover o domínio em questão dos resultados de pesquisa do Google:

1. Fazer login do site [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/%E2%80%8E)
2. Escolher da lista de sites existentes o site pretendido
3. No menu lateral, escolher `Google Index`

   [image: Captura de Tela]
4. Escolher a sub-opção `Remove URLs`

   [image: Captura de Tela]
5. Uma vez na página, no lado direito temos um botão para criar uma nova solicitação de remoção:

   [image: Captura de Tela]
6. Após clique no botão é preciso introduzir o endereço pretendido:

   [image: Captura de Tela]
7. Se aparecer a caixa a perguntar qual o tipo de remoção pretendida, deverás escolher para remover da cache e dos resultados de pesquisa.

   [image: Captura de Tela]

Desta forma, não só garantes que bloqueaste o acesso do `crawler` ao site, mas garantes também que o site em questão vai deixar de aparecer nos resultados de pesquisa evitando a possibilidade de erros.

<sup>Parte das instruções podem ser encontradas nesta página de [Ajuda do Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663427?hl=en).</sup>

Comment: Boa ilustração :) +1

Answer (score 9):

Você pode usar um robots.txt com negação total:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Com o tempo, seu site será removido do indexador do Google. Mais dicas aqui: http://davidwalsh.name/robots-txt

Comment: Eu quero tirar um google site do index. No Google Sites eu não tenho controle sobre o robots.txt

Comment: Isso serve também para caso eu ter um site velho no diretório /2013 e quero que o google só veja o /2014?

Comment: @paulomartinhago serve sim, é só usar `Disallow: /2013`, mas lembre-se que leva tempo para ser refletido.

Comment: @JaderDias você não tinha passado essa informação antes... Pelo que pesquisei, nesse caso não há como.

Comment: Bacana Tiago. Obrigado por esclarecer :D

Answer (score 6):

O Google costuma sugerir/preferir que remoções sejam feitas através de informação útil aos bots (os robôs que andam pela internet a indexar conteúdo).

**Sugiro quatro alternativas** que podem ser usadas complementarmente:

- Remover o conteúdo do `robots.txt` e deixar somente:

  ```
  User-agent: *
  Disallow: /
  ```
- Inserir uma meta tag na no `<head`> da página home/index/principal

  ```
  <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
  ```
- Esvaziar o `sitemap.xml`
- Remover o URL manualmente na consola do webmaster tools:

  [image: Captura de Tela]

  <sub>(Note que esta imagem foi feita hoje, do meu webmaster tools.

  Você refere que já não existe essa opção, mas ele ainda existe. [Só mudou de lugar.](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)).</sub>