# Como consertar indexação de um site no Google

Tags: google, seo

Tenho um site que já está indexado pelo Google, mas como já publiquei no endereço quando o site ainda estava em testes, o Google indexou alguns resultados como URLs quebrados, páginas teste, descrições erradas , etc.

Preciso criar um novo domínio para indexar tudo de maneira correta, ou há alguma forma manual para fazer a re-indexação desse site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O google re-indexa automáticamente o site. Existem ferramentas do Google para isto. Dê uma iolhada nesta pergunta sobre isso: [Como remover um site do Google?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6833/129)

À parte disso eu diria que o google gosta de estabilidade. Um dominio demasiado novo não vai receber muita atênção do Google, por isso mudar de dominio demasiado facilmente é mau.

O que você deve fazer é criar um site map e fazer redirects das páginas que não existem.

Sobre sitemap, é um ficheiro som nome `sitemap.xml` que deve estar na toor do site com informação sobre os links do site. Pode gerar um automaticamente aqui: http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ e depois editar para corrigir detalhes.

O Google tem uma página (em Inglês) bem informativa sobre o sitemap: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en

Fica um exemplo da sintaxe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
  xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" 
  xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
  <url> 
    <loc>http://www.example.com/foo.html</loc> 
    <image:image>
       <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc> 
    </image:image>
    <video:video>     
      <video:content_loc>
        http://www.example.com/video123.flv
      </video:content_loc>
      <video:player_loc allow_embed="yes" autoplay="ap=1">
        http://www.example.com/videoplayer.swf?video=123
      </video:player_loc>
      <video:thumbnail_loc>
        http://www.example.com/thumbs/123.jpg
      </video:thumbnail_loc>
      <video:title>Grilling steaks for summer</video:title>  
      <video:description>
        Get perfectly done steaks every time
      </video:description>
    </video:video>
  </url>
</urlset>
```