# Como ocultar um site dos buscadores?

Tags: seo

Tenho um site que foi indexado com 115 páginas, e 3/4 estão com os links antigos.

O novo projeto está em desenvolvimento, então a ideia é remover o site atual do buscadores, e após o término do mesmo, adiciona-lo novamente.

Já li aqui no próprio site o artigo [Como remover um site do google](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6833/como-remover-um-site-do-google), mas a ferramenta utilizada dentro da plataforma para Webmasters já foi atualizada.

O que fiz até então foi deletar todo o conteúdo do site, deixando apenas um arquivo *robots.txt* da seguinte forma:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /
```

Também acabei de criar um arquivo chamado *index.php*, com uma estrutura básica HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Acho que você pode de cara colocar um redirect permanente para todos os links antigos apontando para os novos (se existirem).

Comment: Acontece que o novo site ainda está sendo desenvolvido. O que quero é apenas remover todas as paginas dos indices do google e outros buscadores, mas, em principio, do Google.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, a principio você fez certo. Apesar de ter começado com user-agent para todos os buscadores, logo abaixo você o desabilitou. Vejo que se o problema persiste em aparecer nos buscadores, colocaria o caminho exato, por exemplo: disallow: meusite/ ou www/ ou public_html/

Vou anexar um link, que me ajuda bastante com SEO dos sites.

https://www.seomarketing.com.br/robots.txt.php