# Não consigo aplicar CSS a botão de input

Tags: html, css, css3

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
<a href="http://compre.vc/"  rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
   <input type="button" value="Clique aqui para comprar" class="splashywaves-effect splashywaves-light splashybtn"  />
</a>
```

Se eu tentar sem o `input`, apenas com o `ahref`, funciona, mas quando eu tento desse jeito aí, não vai.
Se eu tentar usando `<button>`, também funciona, porém, eu preciso que o link seja nofollow, já que é link externo.

Ps: O código CSS

```
button.splashybtn:hover, button.splashybtn-large:hover {
     background-color:#000000;
}



.splashyz-depth-1-half, button.splashybtn:hover, button.splashybtn-large:hover, button.splashybtn-floating:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12),0 3px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
a:active.splashy, a:hover.splashy {
    outline: 0;
}
.splashywaves-effect {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: .3s ease-out;
}
button.splashybtn, button.splashybtn-large {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #E8562A;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    transition: .2s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button.splashybtn, button.splashybtn-large, button.splashybtn-floating, button.splashybtn-large, button.splashybtn-flat {
    font-size: 1rem;
    outline: 0;
}
button.splashybtn, button.splashybtn-large, button.splashybtn-flat {
   border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.splashyz-depth-1, .splashycard-panel, .splashycard, .splashytoast, button.splashybtn, button.splashybtn-large, button.splashybtn-floating, .splashydropdown-content, .splashycollapsible, .splashyside-nav {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}











button.splashybtn1 {    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #26a69a;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    transition: .2s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button.splashybtn1 {    font-size: 1rem;
    outline: 0;
}
button.splashybtn1 {    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
button.splashybtn-flat1 {    font-size: 1rem;
    outline: 0;
}
button.splashybtn-flat1 {    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
button.splashybtn-floating1 {    font-size: 1rem;
    outline: 0;
}
button.splashybtn-large1 {    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #26a69a;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    transition: .2s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button.splashybtn-large1 {    font-size: 1rem;
    outline: 0;
}
button.splashybtn-large1 {    font-size: 1rem;
    outline: 0;
}
button.splashybtn-large1 {    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.splashywaves-effect1 {    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: .3s ease-out;
}
```

Eis o que está acontecendo. Esta url é o link direto do arquivo html: `lucrebem.com.br/va/artigos-complexos/splashcss` Mas o mesmo arquivo é carregado e exibido em um pop up que aparece no site, aqui: `lucrebem.com.br` O popup aparece alguns segundos depois da página ser carregada. Como pode observar, no popup os botões não aparecem.

Screenshot da pagina arquivo html:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Screenshot da página carregada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [Edit] sua pergunta e adicione o css que tentou fazer. E explica melhor o objetivo, não entendi o motivo de usar o `input` e usar o `rel="nofollow"`

Comment: Simplesmente não faz sentido utilizar um `input` dentro de um elemento `a`. Qualquer coisa que você faça assim, será gambiarra, fugindo de qualquer padrão, especificação ou recomendação. Não faça isso. Se você precisa da aparência de um botão, estilize com CSS o próprio elemento `a` da forma que fique como desejar. Pode ler sobre isso [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/710089/1452488).

Comment: Nesse caso não posso fazer o estilo no `href`, precisa ser num botão. Se eu utilizar `button`, não tem como usar o atributo `nofollow`?

Comment: Só uma dica: **Tá uma gambiarra tremenda, e uma bagunça que só** use nome de classes significativas.

Answer (score 1):

Como você precisa que seja `nofollow`, você pode usar meta tag HTML nas páginas que não devem ser indexados nos mecanismos de busca:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

Mais detalhes sobre isso você pode ler:

- [Como evitar que um site seja listado no Google](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78792/51124)
- [Como remover um site do Google?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6833/51124)

Sobre o [`rel="nofollow"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_rel.asp), você só consegue usá-lo na tag `a`.

Você pode seguir a dica no [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207004/n%C3%A3o-consigo-aplicar-css-a-bot%C3%A3o-de-input#comment423323_207004) do Anderson:

> Simplesmente não faz sentido utilizar um input dentro de um elemento
>   a. Qualquer coisa que você faça assim, será gambiarra, fugindo de
>   qualquer padrão, especificação ou recomendação. Não faça isso. **Se você
>   precisa da aparência de um botão, estilize com CSS o próprio elemento
>   a da forma que fique como desejar.**

Para você fazer isso, você pode criar uma classe para botões. Por exemplo, no seu código CSS, no lugar de `button` você coloca `a` e acrescenta essas classes no componente:

```
 <a href="http://compre.vc/" class="splashywaves-effect splashywaves-light splashybtn" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
      Clique aqui para comprar
 </a>
```

Lembrando que não é só mudar de `button` para `a`, isso é um exemplo. No seu código você terá que fazer as modificações para não interferir nas outras partes. Veja:

```css
a.splashybtn:hover,
a.splashybtn-large:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.splashyz-depth-1-half,
a.splashybtn:hover,
a.splashybtn-large:hover,
a.splashybtn-floating:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

a:active.splashy,
a:hover.splashy {
  outline: 0;
}

.splashywaves-effect {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}

a.splashybtn,
a.splashybtn-large {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #E8562A;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.splashybtn,
a.splashybtn-large,
a.splashybtn-floating,
a.splashybtn-large,
a.splashybtn-flat {
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: 0;
}

a.splashybtn,
a.splashybtn-large,
a.splashybtn-flat {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.splashyz-depth-1,
.splashycard-panel,
.splashycard,
.splashytoast,
a.splashybtn,
a.splashybtn-large,
a.splashybtn-floating,
.splashydropdown-content,
.splashycollapsible,
.splashyside-nav {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

a.splashybtn1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.splashybtn1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: 0;
}

a.splashybtn1 {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

a.splashybtn-flat1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: 0;
}

a.splashybtn-flat1 {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

a.splashybtn-floating1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: 0;
}

a.splashybtn-large1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.splashybtn-large1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: 0;
}

a.splashybtn-large1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  outline: 0;
}

a.splashybtn-large1 {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.splashywaves-effect1 {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://compre.vc/" class="splashywaves-effect splashywaves-light splashybtn" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"> 
  Clique aqui para comprar
</a>
```

Comment: Eu já disse duas vezes que não posso usar o `<a href>` sozinho. Está havendo conflito com outras classes do CSS, por isso eu pedi por um botão ou um input.

Comment: @MathewRiver, já criou uma classe só para o `button`? Tipo `.button {background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #333333; }`

Comment: `splashybtn` é a classe própria do botão.

Comment: @MathewRiver, editei a resposta com mais informações. Você não consegue colocar `rel="nofollow"` no `button`. Quando você falou que "está havendo conflito com outras classes do CSS", é porque você não pode simplesmente mudar tudo, provavelmente a tag `a` é usada em várias partes do seu código. Minha resposta é um exemplo para que você possa adaptar seu código.

Comment: Veja o que está acontecendo. Esta url é o link direto do arquivo html: http://lucrebem.com.br/va/artigos-complexos/splashcss
Mas o mesmo arquivo é carregado e exibido em um pop up que aparece no site, aqui: http://lucrebem.com.br/
O popup aparece alguns segundos depois da página ser carregada.
Como pode observar, no popup os botões não aparecem.